# What are the architectural differences between Erlang/OTP and OpenResty?

Tags: erlang-otp, openresty

In Erlang/OTP, I've read how light weight processes, the actor model, and supervisors are important in creating reliable services. How would this compare to OpenResty (master/worker, async IO, embedded Lua)?

I am curious over a general architectural overview on the main concepts to better understand how OpenResty would be used alongside (or instead of)  Erlang/OTP.

Answer (score 0):

These two links partially answers the question:

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/master/README.markdown

> The Lua interpreter or LuaJIT instance is shared across all the
>   requests in a single nginx worker process but request contexts are
>   segregated using lightweight Lua coroutines.
>
> Loaded Lua modules persist in the nginx worker process level resulting
>   in a small memory footprint...

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/wiki/Introduction

> ...for each incoming request, lua-nginx-module creates a coroutine to run user code to process the request, and the coroutine will be destroyed when the request handling process is done. Every coroutine has its own independent global environment, which inherits shared read-only common data.
>
> ...lua-nginx-module can handle tens of thousands of concurrent requests with very low memory overhead. According to our tests, the memory overhead for each request in lua-nginx-module is only 2 KB or even half smaller if LuaJIT is used.